# gmail is rejecting my e-mails to a recipient with a gmail address with a 550-5.7.26

Tags: postfix, spf, gmail

I have a fairly straight forward email setup using postfix.  Within my house running on a raspberry-pi to which my router forwards all ports. I have a postfix instance that can see incoming mail.  A MX record for my e-mail domain (hartley-consultants.com) points at this (external) ip address.  Although it only changes infrequently it can be blocked for outgoing mails, so I have a second server on a virtual instance in the cloud with its own dedicated ip address. This also runs postfix and also has an MX record for hartley-consultants.com pointing at its ip address.  All outgoing mail from my home instance is routed through that cloud server.  Its  been setup this way for a long time (at least 5 years).

My dns server for hartley-consultants.com also has a TXT record with the contents `v=spf1 mx -all`

A month or so ago I suddenly started getting rejections from like this

```
This is the mail system at host asgard.hartley-consultants.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<xxxxxx@gmail.com>: host
    gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c1b::1a] said: 550-5.7.26 This
    message fails to pass SPF checks for an SPF record with a hard 550-5.7.26
    fail policy (-all). To best protect our users from spam and 550-5.7.26
    phishing, the message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. k13-20020a5d66cd000000b002185e450efbsi9129616wrw.664 -
    gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

As part of the headers to this message added by postfix is

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; asgard.hartley-consultants.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 68A463A2807
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; alan.chandler@hartley-consultants.com
Arrival-Date: Mon, 13 Jun 2022 21:49:42 +0100 (BST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxx@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxxx@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.26
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.26 This message fails to pass SPF checks for an
    SPF record with a hard 550-5.7.26 fail policy (-all). To best protect our
    users from spam and 550-5.7.26 phishing, the message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. k13-20020a5d66cd000000b002185e450efbsi9129616wrw.664 -
    gsmtp
```

As I am pretty much retired now, this e-mail domain only sends a few e-mails a month so I need to fix it but not urgently.  However I went to googles help and it didn't give any idea what I am doing wrong

Can someone here explain what google thinks is wrong and what I need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to the problem probably lies in this:

```
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c1b::1a] said:
```

which shows that you were talking to gmail over IPv6 but the hosts in your MX records only have IPv4 addresses in DNS so that is all that will be covered by your SPF record which defers to the MX record.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it - and its working but I am not sure if its this or another change I made to postfix to use the correct server name

Answer (score 2):

The SPF record for hartley-consultants.com must include the IP address of the host you’re sending email from.

Google complains that the IP address you’re sending from is not authorised. (I don’t see an IP address in your question so can’t verify.)

I’m looking at the SPF record for your domain and see that two IP addresses are authorised:

```
$ spftrace hartley-consultants.com
hartley-consultants.com
│   "v=spf1 mx -all"
├── mx → hartley-consultants.com (lookups: 1/10, nested: 2/10)
│   ├── mail.hartley-consultants.com
│   │   └── 94.173.170.110
│   └── asgard.hartley-consultants.com
│       └── 213.138.108.48
│   not-match
└── all match result=fail
fail
```

Make sure to include the IP address you’re sending from in your SPF policy. For example, you could add a specific IPv4 address to your current SPF policy: `"v=spf1 mx ip4:11.22.33.44 -all"`

Comment: Hi May ask what package you have installed for the spftrace command you have used?

Comment: @ZarehKasparian It’s a bit of a sneak peek, really … not in distros, but you can find it [here](https://crates.io/crates/spftrace).

Comment: @ZereahKasparian 213.138.108.48 is the computer running postfix that is trying to send to google.  However I did notice that postfix "myorigin" is set to a cloud provider name for my machine.  I'll try the change to the spf record and see if it solves it

Comment: @ZarehKasparian the changes you suggested didn't work.  However, I did find a fix which seems to have worked - see my edit

Comment: @akc42 which changes?

Comment: @ZarehKasparian I added an `ip4:213.138.108.48` to the spf record like you suggested

Comment: @akc42 "@glts" suggested solutions for you it wasn't me

Comment: @ZarehKasparian apologies to both of you